Volts AC reduction by 10%
Automotive application.  Wheel speed sensor is a passive system. .45 to 1.6 volts ac. I need to drop this ever changing and moving number by 10%.  Smaller tires on the rear and need to add something to the rear wiring to decrease the ac voltage by the tire size decrease,10%.  At 30 mph the car sees a 3 mph delta from front to rear and it freaks out.

We don't know the properties of the sensor output or the properties of the input. Therefore we can't suggest a circuit that will work for you. Cheapest option that is guaranteed to work, won't damage anything, and even street legal is to use correct size tires.

So use the websites from the tire manufacturers to choose tire sizes that give the same rolling radius ie won't affect the speed readings.

Cheat with a microcontroller? Read the input, compute corresponding output, fake the speed sensor output signal?

What lets you assume it is the AC voltage and not the frequency, that is used to calculate the speed.

It's a racing application. To get an edge, I need to change rear tire size, I can't afford to change front tire size. They need to be different.  I also need my traction control and abs etc. It's just what happens in motorsports, being first to do what others can't. I guess it could be the frequency not the volts but Bosch explains that they use the volts.  Maybe that's just a general statement.

it's a car question, you are not the first to try this sucessfully, ask in mechanics.
